# How to sum in SQL increasingly by date?

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with dates and int values and I want to create a new column with the sum of these int values increasingly by date.

Like, if I have [date1, date2, date3] and [1, 2, 3] columns, I want a new one with [1, 3, 6]. How can I do it?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Wbich RDBMS you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would use `+`:

```
select col1 as newcol1, (col1 + col2) as newcol2, (col1 + col2 + col3) as newcol3
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a new column with the sum of these int values
>   increseangly by date.

You didn't mention what RDBMS you are using, but if you are using SQL Server or postegre, or any database system that supports ranking functions, then you can do this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT [Date], id,
    row_number() over(order by date) as rn
  FROM table1
) 
SELECT
  Date, id,
  (SELECT SUM(id) FROM CTE AS c2 WHERE c2.rn <= c1.rn ) AS Sum
FROM CTE as c1;
```

This will give you:

```
|  Date | id | Sum |
|-------|----|-----|
| date1 |  1 |   1 |
| date2 |  2 |   3 |
| date3 |  3 |   6 |
```

[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7be4b/11)